# Is it possible to use Information Gain metric for CART?

Tags: cart, entropy

I've been looking for an example of CART using Information Gain but haven't found one. This made me wonder if it was even possible, so I tried to train one manually (by hand) using the dataset below and I ran into a problem when trying to make a split using a categorical attribute of more than two categories.

[image: weather dataset]

$$
H(Y)=0.9403
$$
$$
IG(Outlook)=0.2467
$$
$$
IG(Temperature)=0.05
$$
$$
IG(Humidity)=0.1518
$$
$$
IG(Windy)=0.0481
$$
By calculating the gains of each attribute, we determine that the best split is given by the Outlook attribute. However, since CART is a binary decision tree I don't know which Outlook categories should go in the left or right branch. So I want to know how it should be done, if possible.